# Batch file to add date & time to beginning of each line of output txt file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to add the date and time to the beginning of each line of an output txt file. So far I have the following;

```
net use N: "\\19.1.25.101\Media\App\Prod Apps\Retail\Com_Dir" /user:TestDomain\ccupd T35t
Set logfile=C:\Update_Com_Log.txt
Echo.========================================================== >> %logfile%
echo.%Date% %Time% >> %logfile%
xcopy N:\*.* C:\Dir_Com  /D /C /R /I /K /Y >> %logfile%
net use N: /delete
```

Which gives me a nice output of;

```
==========================================================  
03/10/2014 14:20:58.47   
N:\Test.txt  
1 File(s) copied
```

However...I'd like it to put the date/time at the beginning of each line, such as;

```
==========================================================
03/10/2014 14:20:58.47  
03/10/2014 14:20:58.47 N:\Test.txt
03/10/2014 14:20:58.47 1 File(s) copied
```

I've tried putting the **%Date% %Time%** at the beginning of the xcopy but it just places the whole line into the log file such as;

```
03/10/2014, 14:32:53.11 Xcopy N:\*.* D:\Wyse_Com  /D /C /R /I /K /Y
```

Which is clearly wrong...

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(untested)

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
net use N: "\\19.1.25.101\Media\App\Prod Apps\Retail\Com_Dir" /user:TestDomain\ccupd T35t
Set "logfile=C:\Update_Com_Log.txt"
(
Echo.==========================================================
echo.%Date% %Time%
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'xcopy N:\*.* C:\Dir_Com  /D /C /R /I /K /Y'
  ) DO ECHO(%DATE% %TIME% %%a
)>"%logfile%"
net use N: /deleteSETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

GOTO :EOF
```

Since I don't have your source data, I can't test this as-is. Should work - in theory.

Note: Use `>>"%logfile%"` to append to an existing file; `>"%logfile%"` tto create the file anew.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :) Would you mind explaining how that works please?

Comment: Parenthesise a group of statements and all output within that group will be redirected to the destination assigned. The `for/f` processes each line of output from the `'single-quoted command'`; the `"delims="` assigns the entire output line to the metavariable `%%a` `echo` that and the date and time - should give you what was required. and `echo(` - well, not necessary here, but `echo(` will produce a newline if it has no arguments, whereas `echo[space]` will report the `echo` staus (on/off). The `(` in `echo(` plays no part in the parenthesis-matching mechanism.