# Batch Script to Grab File Name and Add to Beginning of Each Line

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to grab the file name from a .LOG file and append it to the beginning of each line in the file, sans extension, with a space between the file name and the line contents. There are many such files in a folder and the script should be performed for each .LOG file in the folder. An example file name looks like this:

```
20160201.log
```

I want to add the file name to each of the lines in the file which look like this:

```
00:00:23    Left    4EEFD9    6.59418mA    0.00003mA    OK     
00:00:23    Right   4EEFEF    6.85377mA    0.00001mA    OK     
00:00:44    Left    4EEFDC    6.32207mA    0.00004mA    OK
```

To give a result of this:

```
20160201    00:00:23    Left    4EEFD9    6.59418mA    0.00003mA    OK     
20160201    00:00:23    Right   4EEFEF    6.85377mA    0.00001mA    OK     
20160201    00:00:44    Left    4EEFDC    6.32207mA    0.00004mA    OK
```

I saw this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17793601/4763797) but it references pulling a filename from a list of filenames and placing at the beginning of each entry respectively, so that doesn't work for me. I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179995/batch-file-to-add-date-time-to-beginning-of-each-line-of-output-txt-file), but since I need to use the file name instead of my current system time that won't work either. I don't have any code to offer...I couldn't use anything conclusive from the questions I found and I'm totally new to batch scripts.

---

EDIT 1: Magoo's code

Here is the current code I'm trying to run using Magoo's answer (Note the comments are my addition for troubleshooting):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\ckemmann\Desktop\Current"
SET "destdir=C:\Users\ckemmann\Desktop\Current\New"

::echo %sourcedir% <I check what I've assigned to sourcedir.
::echo %destdir% <And to destdir.
::pause

FOR %%f IN ("%sourcedir%\*.log") DO >"%destdir%\%%~nf.out" (
 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%%f") DO (
  ECHO %%~nf   %%a
 )
)

::pause <I catch the batch script telling me that the system cannot find the path specified.

GOTO :EOF
```

As shown in the code, I get a complaint from windows saying that it can't find the file path...even though that's the one I copied from the folder properties.

---

EDIT 2:

Since I didn't hear back on my edit 1 I went with Arescet's answer. I sadly don't seem to have any way around the slowness of the script. My final code is the same as what he provided in his answer.

Comment: Are you supplying the filename, or should it be auto-detected, or does it beam in from Alpha Centauri?

Comment: @Magoo - How do you mean supplying? I have a folder full of these .LOG files and I want the .bat script to grab the file name of each file, open the file, add the file name w/o extension to the beginning of each line and then close it again. I shall clarify the question to match this comment.

Comment: Magoo's answer is likely faster, as i have a `ren` and a `del` command, but in the end we both have something like `echo %stuff% >endFile.log`, which as i mentioned is the culprit of the 'slowness'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /r "C:\PATH TO WHEREVER\" %%G in (*.log) do (
    ren "%%~G" "reWrite.temp"
    for /f "tokens=*" %%H in (reWrite.temp) do (
        echo %%~nG %%H >> %%~nG.log
    )
    del "reWrite.temp"
)
pause
```

This takes all `.log` files in `"C:\PATH TO WHEREVER\"`, renames them, and writes the filename and data line by line into the original name, then deletes the file when done. @Magoo's answer clearly tops mine, but a different solution should help you understand different ways to solve future desires.

Comment: Thanks Arescet. The script you provided works well...with one caveat. Due to the fact that my .log files are rather long (several thousand lines per file), the batch script is running quite slowly. I'm wondering if there's any way to speed up this script.

Comment: The slow part is almost certainly writing the new line, of which i can think of no way to avoid this. @Magoo's answer has this too. At the very least this can be run in the background, without having to focus on it.

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR %%f IN ("%sourcedir%\*.log") DO >"%destdir%\%%~nf.out" (
 FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%%f") DO (
  ECHO %%~nf   %%a
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

Decoding...

Take the files matching "*.log" from the specified directory, assign their names to `%%f`

create a new file `%%~nf`.out in the destination directory. Read each line from `%%f` to `%%a` and `echo` that line, prefixed by `%%~nf` and a few spaces.

`%%~nf` means the name part only of `%%f`.

The redirector `>` createas a new file and in the position it's been placed, accepts the output of the `echo` into that file instead of the normal echo-to-console.

Comment: I'm sure I'm doing this wrong...I've updated my question with an attempt to implement your code, but for some reason windows is not happy with my file path. I must be dividing by 0 somewhere.